Customize hour and minute part of the MUI x time picker
Below is one of the demos on https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/time-picker/
Did not have any luck investigating but does anyone know how to:

make the hours part in ascending order, i.e 01/02..12 instead of 12/01...11
show only certain minutes and hide others, e.g only show 00 and 30 and hide everything else



I have the second one solved by using timeSteps={{ minutes: 30 }} property
